# Excel VBA Code needed to connect 3 slicers to pivot table without right clicking and selecting report connections for each slicer

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I recorded a macro to see if there was a way after I inserted 3 slicers, to select report connections for each of the slicers to select pivot table without having to
right click and select report connections for each slicer.

This is the below macro code from the recorder:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'slicer 1

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Team Member Name")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Team_Member_Name").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))
    'slicer 2
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Opportunity Owner Name")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Opportunity_Owner_Name").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))
    'slicer 3
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Account Record Type")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Account_Record_Type").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))

End Sub
```

when I run the code, it gives me the following error

> Run-time error '1004':
> Unable to get PivotTables property of the Workclass sheet

Any help provided would be great and been searching for the last few hours and nothing. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too - changing `ActiveSheet.PivotTables...` to reference the sheet the PT is in explicitly (i.e. `Sheets("Sheetx").PivotTables...` worked for me.